# Show only chosen options from multi choice column in another colum as choices

Tags: lookup-column, choice-field

I have column 1, multichoice column and from that column I choose few choices which I want to be seen in another column 2 (choice field also) (it can be in same list or in different, doesn't matter).

To make an example, I have 5 options in multi choice field column Food. I chose 3 options (1. Smashed potato, 2. Caesar salad and 3. Muffin). I want only those three options to be available in another column (column 2). I don't care if other choice options are visible but disabled or only chosen three are visible.

Do you have any suggestion how to manage this?

I cannot use VS, only Sharepoint 2013, SP designer 2013 or scripts which I can implement in pages.

Comment: Question is not clear. What is the exact requirement ?

Comment: What is not clear? I need to present those three choices from one column in another choice column.